# Is there a way to fix this avoiding serde and using nanoserde instead?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm using serde only to do this easy thing. I think I can use [nanoserde](https://github.com/not-fl3/nanoserde) instead but I don't know how.

I'm using serde like this:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    pub team: Team,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Team {
    pub id: String,
    // others here
}

// ...

if api_call.status().is_success() {
    match serde_json::from_slice::<Player>(
        &hyper::body::to_bytes(api_call.into_body()).await.unwrap(),
    ) {
        Ok(player) => {
            // use player.team here

            // do something else
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("{err}");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with:

```rust
match nanoserde::DeBin::de_bin::<Player>(
   &hyper::body::to_bytes(api_call.into_body()).await.unwrap(),
) {
  // ...
}
```

with no luck: it doesn't like the generics.

And tried this too:

```rust
let player: Player = nanoserde::DeBin::deserialize_bin(
  &hyper::body::to_bytes(api_call.into_body()).await.unwrap(),
).unwrap();
```

but this doesn't work, error:

```rust
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Bin deserialize error at:8 wanted:1 bytes but max size is 1161', src\cli.rs:85:10
```

What does this mean?

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please provide a proper [MRE] with your tokio error message. If you don't give us an actual code we can reproduce and fix, this is pretty much a programming request, which is against the guidelines of stackoverflow.

Comment: Its weird that you changed from `serde_json` to `DeBin`. Surely you'd want `DeJson`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you were lacking minimal reproducible examples, here's one for your `serde` code:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    pub team: Team,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Team {
    pub id: String,
    // others here
}

// ...
fn main() {
    let data = br#"{"team":{"id":"42"}}"#;

    match serde_json::from_slice::<Player>(data) {
        Ok(player) => {
            println!("Team: {}", player.team.id);
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("{err}");
        }
    };
}
```

```
Team: 42
```

Now let's see if we can rewrite this in nanoserde:

```rust
use nanoserde::DeJson;

#[derive(DeJson, Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    pub team: Team,
}

#[derive(DeJson, Clone)]
pub struct Team {
    pub id: String,
    // others here
}

// ...
fn main() {
    let data = r#"{"team":{"id":"42"}}"#;

    match Player::deserialize_json(data) {
        Ok(player) => {
            println!("Team: {}", player.team.id);
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("{err}");
        }
    };
}
```

```
Team: 42
```

Note that we have to use a `&str` instead of a `&[u8]` here.

If we are 100% stuck with a `&[u8]`, you can use `from_utf8`:

```rust
use nanoserde::DeJson;

#[derive(DeJson, Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    pub team: Team,
}

#[derive(DeJson, Clone)]
pub struct Team {
    pub id: String,
    // others here
}

// ...
fn main() {
    let data = br#"{"team":{"id":"42"}}"#;

    match std::str::from_utf8(data).map(Player::deserialize_json) {
        Ok(Ok(player)) => {
            println!("Team: {}", player.team.id);
        }
        Ok(Err(err)) => {
            eprintln!("{err}");
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("{err}");
        }
    };
}
```

```
Team: 42
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What I'm stucked with right now is `hyper::body::to_bytes` thing. Is there a way to have a string from it? This is a very hot path of my code and I need to make it really fast.

Comment: Isn't more appropriate to use DeBin in this case?

Comment: Depends on how your data is encoded .. if it's json, you need to use a json encoder. `DeBin` is a completely different encoding than `DeJson`. Look at my third example, it does specifically that: converting a bytes object to a string (through `std::str::from_utf8`). `from_utf8` is very fast, all it does is iterating over it once to make sure it is utf8 compatible.

Comment: Ok. But what does DeBin? Isn't from bytes?

Comment: Yes it is from bytes. So what's your point? It's like saying you have a german sentence that doesn't contain umlauts, so you can put an english reader at it because he knows all the letters. It's like trying to decode json with a toml reader. `Bin` is a different encoding, it is **not** json based.